# Python 2.7 UDP Port Scanner

Tags: python, udp

Can you help me with the program now the problem is that when I enter localhost my program cannot find the open port or the closed one, if you really want to help me and you know how to solve it or fix it, please just compile my code separately just for me right now the program for some reason can’t get to receive a message from the host, I searched the entire Internet and can’t find anywhere the scanner has multiple UDP ports

```
import socket
import sys
# Ask for input
remoteServer    = raw_input('Enter a remote host to scan: ')
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)
print( "-" * 60)
print ('Please wait, scanning remote host', remoteServerIP)
print( "-" * 60)
for port in range(1,1025):
        try:
         sock=socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
         sock.sendto('hello',(remoteServerIP,port))
          #sock.settimeout(1)
         data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
         if data != None:
            print ('Port {}:      Open'.format(port))
         else:
            print ('Port {}:     Closed'.format(port))
         sock.close()
        except socket.error as sock_err:
            if(sock_err.errno == socket.errno.ECONNREFUSED):
                 print sock_err('Connection refused')
        except socket.gaierror:
         print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
        except socket.error:
         print "Couldn't connect to server"
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print 'You pressed Ctrl+C'
```

Comment: Why would you receive a response from the host?  Are you running a service on a localhost port to listen for, and respond to, "hello"?

Comment: @FiddleStix Yes, but there are some problems ??

Comment: Your expectations are misplaced. Where does it say that an arbitrary service running on an arbitrary port has to send you a reply to an arbitrary piece of data sent as a request? You need to (1) close your sockets when finished with them (2) connect them to the target and (3) send *two* requests with a delay in between, which if the target doesn't exist will result in an exception on the second send.

Comment: why is this question titled and tagged for Python 2.7 and yet you use Python 3 `print` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use ICMP packet.For the program to work, you need to enter python    
I publish my code because the answer to this question is practically nonexistent and the task is actually difficult.

```
  import socket
    import sys
    import subprocess
    def getServiceName(port, proto):
        try:
            name = socket.getservbyport(int(port), proto)
        except:
            return None
        return name
    UDP_IP = sys.argv[1]
    for RPORT in range(int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3])):
        MESSAGE = "ping"
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        if client == -1:
            print("udp socket creation failed")
        sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
        if sock1 == -1:
            print("icmp socket creation failed")
        try:
            client.sendto(MESSAGE.encode('utf_8'), (UDP_IP, RPORT))
            sock1.settimeout(1)
            data, addr = sock1.recvfrom(1024)
        except socket.timeout:
            serv = getServiceName(RPORT, 'udp')
            if not serv:
                pass
            else:
                print('Port {}:      Open'.format(RPORT))
        except socket.error as sock_err:
                if (sock_err.errno == socket.errno.ECONNREFUSED):
                    print(sock_err('Connection refused'))
                client.close()
                sock1.close()
```

Comment: if you `connect` the socket then you'll often get errors back appropriately from localhost UDP, any other hosts the packets often just disappear and you have to timeout.

Comment: also why do you keep opening and closing sockets? you're not binding or connecting either so they can just be reused for each test, especially the ICMP socket.  you need to be parsing the result as well, if any other ICMP packet comes in (from some unrelated code) your code will also receive it and needs to know to ignore it